# JavaScript - extremely confused on removing elements from Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, easeljs, createjs

I'm making a 2D, top-down Zelda style web rpg single player in JavaScript.

When the player (purple shirt) walks near a cat, it will "rescue" it... which basically removes the `animalContainer` from the `ContainerOfAnimals` (thereby removing animalContainer's BMP from the stage), and then add the id of that animalContainer to a `rescuedTotal_Array`...

The weird thing is, In the pic below, I'm able to rescue `animalContainer2` and *then* rescue `animalContainer1`... But if I go from `animalContainer1` to `animalContainer2`, it throws a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` error.
```

... 
**Basically:**

**Working way: get ID 22, then up to ID 21** ->>> One thing I notice with this is that the element name doesn't change for the ID... not sure why... so for the broken way... it may not be able to even associate element name `animalContainer2` with an ID? But I don't know how the ID and the name could get disassociated like that..

```
ID in rescued array...: 22, element name: animalContainer1, rescued array length: 2, elem index pos: 0, index: 0

ID in rescued array...: 21, element name: animalContainer1, rescued array length: 2, elem index pos: 1, index: 0
```

**Broken way- throws error: get ID 21, then down to ID 22**

```
ID in rescued array...: 21, element name: animalContainer1, rescued array length: 1, elem index pos: 0, index: 0 

1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```
        function grabIt(NPC_id, index) {
            //check if NPCid already exists in array before adding...
            if ($.inArray(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index].id, rescuedTotal_Array) == -1) {
                rescuedTotal_Array.push(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index].id);
            }
            if (rescuedTotal_Array.length == 2) {
                for (var z = 0; z < rescuedTotal_Array.length; z++) {
                    console.log("ID in rescued array...: " + rescuedTotal_Array[z] + ", \n element name: " + ContainerOfAnimals.children[index].name + ", rescued array length: " + rescuedTotal_Array.length + ",\n elem index pos: " + z + ",\n index: " + index);
                }
            }
            //when I remove the first added element to rescuedTotalArray... the 2nd element's index assumes first added element's index... (goes from 1 to 0)
            console.log(index);
            console.log("element removed: " + ContainerOfAnimals.children[index]);
            stage.update();
            ContainerOfAnimals.removeChild(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index]);
            updateHUD();
        }
```

**I have no idea why the order in which I store elements in the array/remove them from the stage would matter...**

---

EDIT: I feel I can solve this issue by removing element from ContainerOfAnimals by element ID instead of by index... by Container object offers no `getChildID()` function...

so I tried:

```
    var childToRemove = document.getElementById(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index]);
    console.log(childToRemove);
    ContainerOfAnimals.removeChild(childToRemove);
```

console.log(childToRemove) gives me `null` for children

But doing this: `console.log(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index].id);` gives me id `21`, which is the correct id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that EaselJS elements aren't DOM elements.

Supposing you want to remove an element by its id, I'd suggest this :

```
function removeElementById(container, id) {
   for (var i=container.getNumChildren(); i-->0;) {
       if (container.getChildAt(i).id===id) {
            container.removeChildAt(i);
            return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

But using the id might not be the best architectural solution. In my EaselJS program I keep a reference to the objects themselves so that I don't have to search them.

Comment: Okay, so let's say I have two parent containers... `ContainerOfItemA` and `ContainerOfItemB`... And I set their ids to `0` and `1` respectively... And `ContainerOfItemA` has children `container1`, `container2`... same for `ContainerOfItemB`... Can I set the children ids to `0` and `1` since they are children even though their IDs are used by other parent containers?

Comment: Also, can you give an example of `I keep a reference to the objects themselves`?

Comment: I'm not sure you should change the id of the elements yourself : they're set by the library and it doesn't seem (I'm not 100% sure) the library works well if you touch that. As for keeping a reference, I mean having a `var myAnimal;` for example [like this](https://github.com/Canop/SpaceBullet/blob/master/src/Mission.js#L107) (in this program I make subclasses of CreateJS classes).

Comment: The original reason I was changing the IDs was because I was passing them in as the index into arrays to access correct json dialog for that easel js element... But I ended up making a `npcName_to_Index(NPC_name)` method that converts NPC_name to correct index like so: `if (NPC_name == "animalContainer1") { index = 0; }` etc... then return that index so the correct json array dialog can be assigned to that element

Comment: Also, why is using the id not the best architectural solution? Isn't that what the ids are there for?

Comment: You don't need to store the id in a variable if you can directly store the reference to the object.

Comment: I just tested your method, it seems to work fine! Couple more questions: You wrote `i-->0;` in the for loop, 1) what is that notation? 2) The javascript is commenting it out. **Next**, Why does my method of removing the child from parent container ContainerOfAnimals not work, and your method does? **Lastly**, before removing the element, I wanted to add the element to array only if it doesn't exist `if ($.inArray(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index].id, rescuedTotal_Array) == -1) {` and then `rescuedTotal_Array.push(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index].id); }`.. but property isn't defined

Comment: 1) that's just the postfix decrement operator followed by a comparison `(i--)>0`. 2) you use directly children which [isn't recommended](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#property_children). 3) this again plays with id, I'm not sure and it starts to be hard to answer in comments (and I'll disconnect for a while soon) so you might want to create another question if your problems aren't all solved.

Comment: Haha I thought it was like *as i approaches 0*... Thanks so much though for your help. I'll create a new question... but will accept your answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35536/discussion-between-growler-and-dystroy)

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that your `rescuedTotal_Array` is an associative Array (or was morphed to one) and could contain something like:

```
rescuedTotal_Array = [1:object,2:object,object:object]
```

The array above has the length of 3. But you cannot access the third element via index 2, because its index is some kind of object.

Try to dump the content of your `rescuedTotal_Array` before accessing it (so you can see if everything is ok). This is not a solution, but it may help you so that you can find the error by yourself. Use something like

```
for (index in rescuedTotal_Array) {
    if (rescuedTotal_Array.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        console.log(rescuedTotal_Array[index]);
    }
    else {
        console.log("no entry found for index: "+index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange... is the output the same in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure whatever if this is the case (I can't know it without taking a look at your whole program), but it could be this:

I assume that your "ContainerOfAnimals" is a HTML element and that you are retrieving it's child nodes using it's .children -property. The thing is that .children -property returns a **"live list"**!

Let me demonstrate:

```
var children = ContainerOfAnimals.children;
console.log(children.length) // 2;

ContainerOfAnimals.removeChild(children[0]);
console.log(children.length) // 1;
```

Let's say that you remove the very first child of ContainerOfAnimals. What happens? The children -list has now changed so that the second element becomes the first element, third element becomes the second element etc...

You could fix this by using a static array containing all the children and like this:

```
var children = [].slice.call(ContainerOfAnimals.children);
console.log(children.length) // 2;

ContainerOfAnimals.removeChild(children[0]);
console.log(children.length) // 2;
```

Now removing the element from the DOM -tree does not remove the element from the children array (which is static). Remember, that [].slice.call does not work in IE8 or lower.

Let me know if this was the problem. I have not enough points to comment, so I had to make a full post :)

Comment: Thanks for this... yeah I figured that the indices were being shifted as such. I tried `var children = [].slice.call(ContainerOfAnimals.children);` then `ContainerOfAnimals.removeChild(children[index]);`, If I tried to remove ID 21 then down to ID 22... it only removes ID 21 and does nothing with ID 22 (still remains shown). If I'm going to just put the elements of ContainerOfAnimals in an array, should I just put animalContainer1 and animalContainer2 in an array to begin with?

Comment: user, I could fix the problem by removing the child element by ID, but Container offers no `getChildByID` method. I then tried using `document.getElementById`, but the results turned up null. See above Code Edit

Comment: document.getElementById takes only one __string__ argument. You are currently calling it with an element reference, which is obviously the problem here. Did my suggestion not work? Did you specify `var children = [].slice.call(ContainerOfAnimals.children);` outside __ grabIt__ function (otherwise it gets overwritten every time you call __grabIt__)? My suggestion only works if you know the initial order of the child elements (I assume you do because you of your __index__ argument). You can also remove them by getting the reference using getElementById, but only if you know the ids beforehand.

Comment: Yes, I do `var children = [].slice.call(ContainerOfAnimals.children);` then `grabIt(NPC_id, index, children);` then in the `grabIt` function I do `ContainerOfAnimals.removeChild(children[index]);`. It still does nothing when I try to grab that second element

Comment: This answer is based on a totally false premise : EaselJS elements aren't DOM elements at all. See http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html

Answer (score -1):

HY,

Try for statement like this:

```
for(var z = rescuedTotal_Array.length; z >= 0; z-- )
```

If you noticed I just turned it around. It starts at the and going backwards. 
It is stupid but, maybe this error is just that :)

Let me know how it goes!

Regards

Comment: Hi Jan, not really sure how iterating through the array the other way attempts to answer the question? Can you elaborate please

Comment: Hm, code that you wrote is completely correct. There is no logical explanation why it doesn't. Somethimes you just have to try stupid way of debuging. Try it won't hurt you...