# Coding: solve bug or move on?

Tags: javascript, testing

I have a general development question...

I've been making this rpg and recently came across this annoying bug. It's driving me nuts, and haven't made progress on other aspects of the game because I've been so focused on solving it. The bug isn't necessarily a show stopper, but it is something that will need to be solved.

Here is the bug: [JavaScript - extremely confused on removing elements from Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254816/javascript-extremely-confused-on-removing-elements-from-container)

My issue is:

- On one hand, if I don't spend the time really thinking about the bug, I will probably never solve it.
- On the other hand, it's preventing me from advancing other aspects of development.

That being said, my question is: If there is one, what's a good rule of thumb on time you should invest into a bug before moving on?

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, or another SO site.

Thanks

Comment: It 's sure this question doesn't belong here. I don't know for other SO sites.

Comment: I think TDD will bring benefits to you

Comment: If it's getting to your creativity, and you are your own boss in this project, then do move on for a while. I can tell by experience that it helps, and the solution might come to you when you least expect it. But do get more people involved. Sometimes bugs are very simple things which we don't notice because human beings tend to not notice their own coding mistakes. Peer review helps a lot. Also you could post a question here on SO about this specific bug, maybe we can help.

Comment: To follow up on what Renan said, rubber duck debugging has helped me find more errors than I'd like to admit.

Comment: @dystroy I think the question belongs here. I just read the help and it fits.

Comment: To add to what @AndyG said: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Comment: @Renan I updated above with the bug

Comment: @Growler I edited your questions to make that link more clear, so people don't think you've uploaded the relevant code to some external site (that gets a lot of questions on hold).

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo what is TDD?

Comment: You're already getting answers there :) Good luck solving your bug

Comment: @Growler: Test Driven Development: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have decided the bug must be fixed, it doesn't matter when you do it. However, the longer the bug persists, the harder it will be to solve, so fixing it early is the best path to success.

Answer (score 2):

[Joel says (see #5)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) you should fix bugs right away.

> That's one reason to fix bugs right away: because it takes less time.
>   There's another reason, which relates to the fact that it's easier to
>   predict how long it will take to write new code than to fix an
>   existing bug.