# Container.id vs getElementById - weird error

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I have a function for my rpg game that simulates grabbing an element in a create js container object by removing it from the container (thereby removing it from the stage) when the player gets near it.

```
function grabIt(NPC_id, index) {
    console.log(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index].id);
    var childToRemove = document.getElementById(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index]);
    console.log(childToRemove);
    ContainerOfAnimals.removeChild(childToRemove);
}
```

The first console.log gives correct id of child: `21`

But when I want to grab the child container object using `getElementById`, the child is `null`.

Why is this?

Comment: You seem to be missing the `.id` on `ContainerOfAnimals.children[index]` inside of the `document.getElementById()`. Nonetheless, you don't need to requery the DOM for the element (by `id`). Just use `ContainerOfAnimals.removeChild(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index]);`

Comment: `.id` refers to the specific child's `id`. `index` refers to its index in the collection. Like I said, don't even use this way anyways, since you already have a reference to the element with `ContainerOfAnimals.children[index]` and you can call `removeChild` with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EaselJS elements have an `id` property but there aren't DOM elements. They're plain JavaScript objects (instances of a subclass of `DisplayObject`). And they're not added to the DOM tree.

Therefore, you can't get them by using `document.getElementById`.

To remove your element, simply do

```
 ContainerOfAnimals.removeChild(ContainerOfAnimals.children[index]);
```

or ([faster](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#method_removeChild))

```
 ContainerOfAnimals.removeChildAt(index);
```

Comment: Okay, I know I need to use that to remove the element. I wasn't aware, however, that EaselJS element ids aren't DOM elements... The reason I was going this route was because of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254816/javascript-extremely-confused-on-removing-elements-from-container

Comment: The answer on this question was totally false.

Comment: I appreciate you letting me know... I started going down the wrong path as to why the heck it wouldn't work given it was a DOM element.. which it isnt